# Deploy nodejs app on ecs

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm try launch Nodejs app on alibabacloud ecs with using **nginx**.

my app is in `/var/www/html/ar_exp` folder

When I run`node app` then app listen `localhost:8080`

my nginx default config:

`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

`

When I check from my ecs server via `curl mydomain.com` or via `wget mydomain.com` response is correct from nodejs app. But when i check it in browser then: `ERR_connection_timed_out`.

For all files in nodejs app folder () i set the following settings:

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`
and 755 for all files

what else would I check?

Comment: It looks like firewall / configuration issue. Is port 80 / 443 exposed on internet on ecs configuration ? (I don't know alibabacloud)
Maybe you should expose nginx on another port ?

Comment: Thank you, @jonathan-muller. nmap from another server shows that the port 80 is opened. Also I opened `ufw allow 80/tcp` and `ufw allow http`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Also before nginx i had an apache and apache default page was available from the Inet

Comment: If this is an app in development, it is usually a good idea to test with ports above 2000. Port n. 80 is usually for HTTP requests while port 443 for HTTPS requests. Beside from the logic of this (why running an NGINX HTTP server on top of Node that already has that full functionality), can you explain what port should your server be listening to? When you check the connection in your browser, do you enter localhost:8080 or else?

Comment: I check in browser mydomain.com, because ecs server doesn't have gui. I use nginx because i don't know how settimg up nodejs for listen 80 port of mydomain. I would like open my node app right via domain name (i.e. with 80 port

Comment: A VERY BIG CORRECTION: `nmap -Pn mydomain.com` from another pc don't show 80 port as open. Also ufw status is inactive

Answer (score 0):

Website inaccessibility from the ECS can be due to following reasons.

1. **OS firewall**: Make sure that the application OS firewall(ufw) settings are properly configured to allow communication to the application port.
2. **VPC Security Group**: Make sure that the security group setting is applied and required communication port is configured.[Details to configure security group](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25387.htm)